# When setting session with express-session on route, it's empty for other routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mocha.js, express-session

When i set my session on a route and try to access to it in another route, the session is empty.

Account route:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')

   req.session.user = req.body._email;
   res.send({error: false});

});
```

And here, its empty. User route:

```
router.get('/me', function(req, res){
   if(!req.session.user){
      res.status(500).send({error:true})
   }else{
      res.send({user: req.session.user})
   }
});
```

Im using express-session.
In my App.js:

```
app.use(session({
   secret: 's3cr3t',
   name : 'myName'
   })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(validator()); 
express.bodyParser()!
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/account', account);
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname +'/public/assets'));
```

Trying it on mocha

```
it('should create session', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/v1/account/login')
        .send({_email: 'test@test.com', _password: 'testtest'})
        .end(function(err, res){
            chai.request(server)
                .get('/api/v1/user/me')
                .end(function(err, res2){
                    res2.should.have.status(200);
                    done();
                });
        });
});
```

Always returning status 500. And i ve already printed req.session on my console and its empty.

Comment: Is there a reason that your test sends `_email`, but the server stores `email` in the session?

Comment: hi, yes, cause i took away some validation. Its wrong in the question but not in my code.